# Sonar display violation message in french

Tags: internationalization, sonarqube, locale, rules

I recently install sonar server and some plug in and i have a strange language issue when sonar displays violation messages, it displays messages in French.

How can i force sonar to display message in English?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the settings on the sonar admin page?

Worse case you could set '-Duser.region=GB -Duser.language=EN' on the script that runs the sonar java process.

Sounds like an odd one

Comment: Thank you but some reports are still in french

Answer (score 0):

As emeraldjava said, some message are localized according to the settings of the JVM which ran the analysis.

If you are using Jenkins you will find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553385/sonar-displays-violation-messages-in-another-language-than-sonar-default-locale).

If, like me, you are using the maven plugin (mvn sonar:sonar), you can define the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` as `-Duser.region=US -Duser.language=en`...

For example, the message `'31' devrait être défini comme une constante` became `'31' is a magic number` after I set the variable and ran an other analysis.