# Sonar displays violation messages in another language than Sonar default locale

Tags: internationalization, sonarqube, locale

After upgrading Sonar 2.10 to Sonar 3.2, some violation messages are displayed in another language than Sonar default locale.

In my case, Sonar default locale is set to "en" in the general configuration settings. I've also checked in Sonar System Info panel that the Java system property "user.language" is set to "en" as well. I don't have installed Sonar French Pack neither. Only the English pack is installed by default. However some messages are still displayed in French ?!?!

Please note that Sonar metrics is triggered by jobs configured in Jenkins. Should I force anything in Jenkins as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the default locale on your Jenkins server is also English.

Comment: Well... I have already force Jenkins to use the language "en" in "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure system" -> "Locale" -> "Default Language". Moreover the option "Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users" is also checked.

Comment: I have also verified in Jenkins System Information that the Java system property "user.language" is set to "en" as well. However In this panel I can also see that there are two environment variables: LANGUAGE and LANG. They are respectively set to "fr_BE:fr" and "fr_BE.UTF-8". As far as I know I didn't set it myself. This might be the cause of my issue. Are these variables automatically set by the OS based on the regional settings of the server ?

Comment: When I was talking about the default locale of your Jenkins server, I should have said: the default locale of the server that runs Jenkins. So indeed, the fact that you can se the environment variables set to fr_BE explains why you get the messages in French. If you want to have the messages in English, you can force the locale by modifying the environment variables for the user that runs Jenkins (=> this is the user that will start the Sonar analysis).

Comment: Thanks Fabrice... As I've guessed also, this was indeed the cause of my issue. I asked our Admin to change the default locale of our Jenkins server and now all violations messages are displayed in the right locale. However that's a bit weird that this issue seems to happen for some violation messages only and not for all messages.